# button - single button with hover and click effect with icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

How can i do two effects for single button. you can catch example from below link.

I just want to change the icon-envelop effect "on hover and click"

1. On hover icon should change its effect, you can see the effect at the bottom of the page with green colored.
2. When click the same button icon should change its effect like the button with cart moving.

jsfiddler would be much appreciated.

thanks for the heads up

[example link](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/)

Comment: What have you tried? You linked to a page where all of these effects are available as a demo. Try combining the two, and ask a question if you run into any problems with this

Comment: i tried.. but its not working..  below was tried so far .btn-7b:hover span {
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(300%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(300%);
 transform: translateY(300%);
}


.btn-7b:before {
 left: 0;
 top: -100%;
}


.btn-7b:hover:before {
 top: 0;
}

Comment: could you pls fiddle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```js
$("button").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#B8A3C1");
});
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    $("button").css("background-color", "#823aa0");
});
```

```css
button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    background: #823aa0;
    border: none;   
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s; 
    outline: none;
}

button:before,
button:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    line-height: 65px;
}

button:before {
    content: "\2663";     
    top: -70px;
    font-size: 50px;  
}

button:hover:before { top: 0px; }

button:after {
    content: "Click";
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 30px;  
}

button:hover:after { top: 70px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button></button>
```

Comment: thanks for your help dude.. i tried same what you did, there is no issue in that.. all want add one more effect for same button when click ..  example : when hover the symbol has rolled down similarly when i click the button the same symbol has to do some other effect like vibrate or spin

Comment: @beep My answer isn't useful that your don't marked it?

Comment: almost okay bro... i just did what you did already... i want one more effect same button ... 1)when hover the "spade" symbol with text should move from right to left and then get back to its position.                                                   2)if click it should show some fade in fade out effect

Comment: thank you so much bro.. u save my time... now i need second reqirement

Comment: well i did copy and paste your code.. unfortunately its not working in my project

Comment: @beep Do you added jquery to your project?

Comment: my detailed requirement is here [http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/]  you can find "ORDER ITEM" button with effect. it happens only when click.. but i want that same effect when hover not by click